# what is the difference between ODCIVARCHAR2LIST and ODCINUMBERLIST?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm using  ODCIVARCHAR2LIST and ODCINUMBERLIST on varchar characters and both functions works and the result is the same. I was wondering if you could explain why i'm not getting an error when using ODCINUMBERLIST? what is my motivation to use ODCIVARCHAR2LIST ?

Thanks

Sorry for not adding my code. I'm using the above functions as a way to brake xml values into rows. after extracting them and "clean" them from all unnecessary characters, each singl value need to looks like this: abc-xyz-aaa-ab1-2db-a-bbb. Then I use this code:

```
select * 
from TABLE(CAST (MULTICAST (SELECT LEVEL FROM DUAL 
CONNECT BY LEVEL < REGEX_COUNT (my_field, 'regex_exp')) as SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST
```

and if I use SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST i get the same result:

abc-xyz-aaa-ab1-2db-a-bbb
abc-www-ffs-cvx-azx-a-ggg
...
...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is probably typo in your snippet,I assume you use `MULTISET` not `MULTICAST`

Here your simplified example

```
select dump(COLUMN_VALUE,16) 
from TABLE(CAST (MULTISET(SELECT LEVEL FROM DUAL 
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 2) as SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST ))
```

returning

```
Typ=1 Len=1: 31
Typ=1 Len=1: 32
```

The [typ = 1](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements001.htm#BABCGCHG) means that a VARCHAR2 was returned

The similar example with `OdciNumberList`

```
select dump(COLUMN_VALUE,16) 
from TABLE(CAST (MULTISET(SELECT LEVEL FROM DUAL 
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 2) as SYS.OdciNumberList ))
```

returns

```
Typ=2 Len=2: c1,2
Typ=2 Len=2: c1,3
```

here type 2 is NUMBER as expected.

The implicit conversion rules are valid here as well, i.e. string with well formatted number may be processed as numbers.

```
SELECT dump(COLUMN_VALUE,16)
FROM TABLE(sys.OdciNumberList('42','43'));

Typ=2 Len=2: c1,2b
Typ=2 Len=2: c1,2c
```

Comment: which one should i use for best practice?

Comment: @user1508682 there is no best practice here, if you work with numbers use `OdciNumberList`, to process `abc-xyz-aaa-ab1-2db-a-bbb` you will need `OdciVarchar2List`